# SSRS Indicator Value Null

Tags: ssrs-2008, indicator

Is there any way to display an indicator when the values are NULL.

[image]

Green = > 10

Red = < 9

There are NULL cells which i want to display as black.

Is there a way around this with an expression?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `SWITCH` expression.

```
=SWITCH (
Fields!MyField.Value >= 10 , "Green",
Fields!MyField.Value > 0, "Red",
True, "Black")
```

The Switch expression will break as soon as it hits the first match, that's why I changed the Red to check for > 0 as it will only get to this point if the first condition is not true.

**Note** This assumes all you values are positive.

If you have negative values you'll need to modify it to something like

```
=SWITCH (
Fields!MyField.Value >= 10 , "Green",
ISNUMERIC(Fields!MyField.Value), "Red",
True, "Black")
```

I've not tested the above but they should be ok.